# I get the same id number with transactions

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hello i have a restaurant application i try to make a function to get transaction number for order but some times i get the same transaction number

```
Function GetTransNo() As String
    Try
        Dim sdate As String = Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
        cn.Open()
        cm = New SqlCommand("Select * From TblCart Where TransNo Like '" & sdate & "%' Order By Id Desc", cn)
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then

            GetTransNo = CLng(dr.Item("Transno").ToString) + 1
        Else
            GetTransNo = sdate & "0001"


        End If
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        cn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
        GetTransNo = ""
    End Try

    Return GetTransNo
End Function
```

and this sub to get orders i get an empty table name and the same transaction number

```
 Sub GetOrder()
        Dim found As Boolean
        Dim tno As String = ""
        cn.Open()
        cm = New SqlCommand("Select * From tblcart Where tableno like '" & LblTable.Text & "' and status like 'Pending'", cn)
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            found = True
            tno = dr.Item("TransNo").ToString
        Else
            found = False
        End If
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()

        If found = True Then
            LblTransNo.Text = tno
            loadcart()
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: Why is this question marked as C#?

Comment: I don't like assuming that SQL is going to give me things the way I want them.  Have you used a SQL tool to validate that you get back what you expect with your query?  I would prefer to retrieve all matching data, sort it myself inside VB then get the max existing ID from that.  When your connection returns raw SQL data, .NET has to then convert that raw data to stick it into a .NET object for you to read/access.  Maybe it doesn't get converted how you think/expect, which is why I prefer to get a larger data set and then manipulate it myself in VB.

Comment: `CLng(dr.Item("Transno").ToString) + 1` Sounds like a recipe for race conditions

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to go down the path of this is in every aspect an absolutely horrible way to number your transactions and it's little wonder you're having inconstant results.  If TransNo is a Long, store it as a long.  If you're looking for the maximum TransNo for a Date, build your query to do just that.  Don't concatenate two distinct bits of data.  Store the Date and store the transaction number.  If you need to display them as a single attribute, do that when you Display it.  Design your database properly and then get a whole heap more robust solution

Comment: @user9938 Can i know the difference for using statment block and this code whats the problem if im not use using statement blcok

Comment: @SOS Whats the difference if i converted to long data type

Comment: Databases already provide mechanisms for generating incrementing numbers, which unlike the code above, take multithreading into account. Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel, and mistakenly assuming the above will never generate the same number, use one of the existing types instead: identity, sequence, etc. Then as mentioned above, format the attributes on dislay.

Comment: @PaulSinnema: I removed the C# tag.